# How do I receive and read a .log extension file in a form in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, logfile

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const showFile = () => {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      const preview = document.getElementById("show-text");
      cosnt file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      const logFile = /log.*/;

      if (file.type.match(logFile)) {
        reader.onload = function (event) {
          preview.innerHTML = event.target.result;
        };
      } else {
        preview.innerHTML = "<span class='error'>It doesn't seem to be a log file!</span>";
      }
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={showFile} />
      <div id="show-text">Choose text File</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to be able to read a log file from the input field and do extra querying. For example, after reading the log file, I would like to count how many '/about' routes have been called and how unique the call is in terms of which machine sent the GET request.

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv2xB.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

I understood this question wrong, but here is a solution: (You can do any file manipulation inside the `parseFile()` function)

Link to the CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/logs-viewer-file-chooser-crq8g)

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { LazyLog } from "react-lazylog";

export default function App() {
  const [logContent, setLogContent] = useState(null);

  function renderLogs() {
    return (
      <LazyLog extraLines={1} enableSearch text={logContent} caseInsensitive />
    );
  }

  const parseFile = async (fileContent) => {
    // Do whatever you want to do with the content of the file
    console.log(fileContent);
  };

  const showFile = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const data = await new Response(file).text();
      await parseFile(data);
      setLogContent(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Logs uploader</h1>

      <input type="file" accept=".log" onChange={showFile} />

      <hr className="divider" />

      <div className="log-container">
        {logContent ? renderLogs() : <h4>No logs</h4>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

You can try this library https://mozilla-frontend-infra.github.io/react-lazylog/, if you don't have access at build time, you need to fetch the `.log` file.

```js
import { LazyLog } from "react-lazylog";

export default function App() {
  const url = "https://online.com/file.log";

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500, width: 902 }}>
      <LazyLog extraLines={1} enableSearch url={url} caseInsensitive />
    </div>
  );
}
```

See the Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/logs-viewer-bsf9s

Comment: This is a neat library! but I just simply want to read the log file and read the data inside for querying.

Comment: @kindred-sol I've made an update to the answer